# I can access iCloud online on my Mac, but can not sign into App Store

Tags: icloud, macos, apple-id, password, mac-appstore

My Mac is running on Sierra 10.12.6. When I try to access App Store on my Mac, it requires a username and password. I am able to login to iCloud online using my Apple ID. However, I can not sign in to App Store using the same Apple ID and the password. Can you pls help?

Comment: You need to login successfully to App Store to be able to download apps, not iTunes. iTunes is (was) for shows, movies and music assuming you are referring to macOS versions prior to Catalina. Btw, which version of macOS is installed on your Mac?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant the app store I wasn't able to login to

Comment: Thx. Can you pls modify your question accordingly then and also mention your macOS version? In addition, when you say “it doesn’t work”, do you mean you can not sign in to App Store using your Apple ID or you can sign in successfully to App Store with your Apple ID but you can not download apps?

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to sign in to App Store?

Comment: No error msg, the user and password bar jitters, as if the data is wrong